# Disabling TimeZone area in Calendar object

Tags: java, calendar, timezone

I am trying to convert an XMLGregorianCalendar object to a Calendar object and my problem is with timezones..

XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGreCal2 = flightSegment.getDepartureDateTime().normalize();

After above code executes xmlGreCal2 value is **2016-03-20T16:00:00.000Z**
but when i try to convert xmlGreCal2 object to a Calendar object time zone value added automatically. 
And cal value is **2016-03-20T16:00:00.000+02:00** after below code executes

Calendar cal = xmlGreCal2.toGregorianCalendar();

So my question is how can i disable this timezone area when converting to Calendar object so that i have the value **2016-03-20T16:00:00.000Z** in Calendar object as expected

Comment: Take a look at this overload: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html#toGregorianCalendar(java.util.TimeZone,%20java.util.Locale,%20javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot erase timezone. It's essential part of the Time. 
What you can actually do is set timezone for GMT which is zero time zone and you will have what you need.

Comment: Thank you. Setting timezone for GMT is worked for me.